# nested select in mysqlite

Tags: sqlite, r

I am learning sqlite using the example from [sqldf](http://code.google.com/p/sqldf/), I have come across example 3 about nested select and I don't quite understand the code:

```
sqldf("select iris.Species '[Species]',
              avg(Sepal_Length) '[Avg of SLs > avg SL]'
       from iris,
         (select Species, avg(Sepal_Length) SLavg
          from iris group by Species) SLavg
       where iris.Species = SLavg.Species
          and Sepal_Length > SLavg
       group by iris.Species")
```

I think the code above is trying to:

- create a table with `[Species]` and `[Avg of SLs > avg SL]` using data from `iris` (from line 1-3)
- create a table named `SLavg` with Species and average Sepal_Length for each Species from `iris` (from line 4-6)

I wonder why `SLavg` is present in line 4-5 for 2 times, I tried removing `SLavg` and sqldf gives me `statement: no such column: SLavg` and `statement: no such column: SLavg.Species`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code queries two columns from cross-join of two tables:

```
select c1,c2 from iris,T2 where .... group by ....
```

Where T2 is a subquery which is given shorthand 'SLavg':

```
select d1, d2 from iris group by ...... // subquery
```

SLavg is used for both subquery name and column name, and that's confusing. Let's give them different names:

```
select 
    iris.Species '[Species]', avg(Sepal_Length) '[Avg of SLs > avg SL]'
from 
    iris, 
    (select Species, avg(Sepal_Length) AVGcol from iris group by Species) AVGtbl
where 
    iris.Species = AVGtbl.Species and Sepal_Length > AVGcol
group by 
    iris.Species
```

Now it should be more understandable:

- the subquery `AVGtbl` produces two columns (`Species`, `AVGcol`)
- the cross-join of `iris` and `AVGtbl` produces four columns (`iris.Species`, `iris.Sepal_Length`, `AVGtbl.Species`, `AVGtbl.AVGcol`).

The `where` clause of top-level `select` operates on these four.